# Why am I not shocked when I touch a tree, and the tree touches a power line?

Tags: energy

Why am I not shocked when I touch a tree, and the tree touches a power line?

Comment: Because you are *really* lucky

Comment: or the tree is very lucky, particularly on a rainy day. Maybe the lines are the new ones that are insulated braids of wire,  in woody areas? Otherwise it is an optical illusion that the tree is touching the wires. In Greece the electricity company goes around pruning trees under unshielded power lines.

Answer (score 3):

Wood is a poor conductor

Oven-Dry Wood has a resistivity of $1.00 \times 10^{14}$ to $1.00 \times 10^{16} \Omega m$
Damp Wood has a resistivity of $1.00 \times 10^3$ to $1.00 \times 10^4 \Omega m$
Copper has a resistivity of $1.68 \times 10^{−8} \Omega m$